# Retrieving mixed data type ( unicode and non unicode data) from nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an automated script in Python which inserts data into SQL Server. My columns are of type nvarchar. For a few, it is identified that it is unable to insert some special characters.

I used N prefix while inserting.

By adding prefix, I need use the N prefix while selecting also, but with prefix characters inserted without N prefix, it is not getting selected.

Is there any way to retrieve both in single select? What are the drawbacks of having mixed data?

Minimal Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHGux.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9plsm.png

My expectation is that both with and without N in where clause it will fetch the data

Comment: `I need use the N prefix while selecting also` - there is no such thing as using "N" when selecting.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you wish to use special characters in your where clause you need to use "N" but that automatically works with all data. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: The best is to insert correct data in the first place. The way it do it is N prefix. When you do your where, you similarly add the N. Otherwise it becomes, **** in **** out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string constant without an `N` prefix is converted according to the database default collation code page. Characters that don't have a matching character in the database collation code page are permanently lost (replaced with `?' or a fallback character).

The inserted data will be reflect the value after the character replacement even if the column is a Unicode data type (nvarchar/nchar) capable of storing Unicode characters. There is no way to retrieve the original data.

Select from the table without the `WHERE` clause to see the changed value.